# Extra Space Before align* and Not Display Equation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, align

There is an extra space between the `section` and the `align*` parts of the page. This does not occur if the equation is simply enclosed in `\[...\]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
\section{Test}
\begin{align*}
  a^2 + b^2 &= c^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Which yields:
[image: pdf]

I could just raise up the `align*` environment using a negative `\vspace`, but I was wondering if there is a more proper way.

**EDIT:**

Having defined:

```
\newcommand{\A}[1]{{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}\begin{align*}#1%
  \end{align*}}}
```

I replaced the necessary `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` with `\A{...}` and now I am getting this (this is my actual document):
[image: larger bottom space]

What could be causing this larger bottom space?

Comment: `align` (and `align*`) has `\abovedisplayskip` space above, which is an elastical length, being about 10pt ;-) This is true for `equation` etc. as well. You could say `\abovedisplayskip=0pt`, of course, in a group preferably

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but just in case, you could use the `\useshortskip` command fromm `nccmath`, just before the `align` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`align` and `align*` use a vertical skip amount of about `10pt` above the environment. This can be set to `0pt`, but this should be done within a group, i.e. use

```
{%
\abovedisplayskip=0pt%
 \begin{align*}
  ...
 \end{align*}
}%
```

Please note, that there's `\belowdisplayskip` as well, having the analogous meaning for the space below the environment. Reducing just one of the skip register values may lead to a non-eye-appealing look of the output.

Setting both to `0pt` is not recommended.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
\section{Test}
\begin{align*}
  a^2 + b^2 &= c^2
\end{align*}
Some other text

\section{Another Test}
{%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt
\begin{align*}
  a^2 + b^2 &= c^2
\end{align*}
}%
Some other text


\section{Another Test}
\begin{align*}
  a^2 + b^2 &= c^2
\end{align*}
Some other text


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll create a custom command to handle that. Thanks!

Comment: This is creating some extra bottom space for me. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: @cabellicar123: I don't see extra bottom space

Comment: See edit. I'm not quire sure what is causing it as it doesn't seem to appear in your example.

Comment: @cabellicar123: I don't think wrapping `align*` in a extra command is a good idea, but are you sure that this `extra` space isn't the sum of the `\belowdisplayskip` and some skip above the next section title?

Comment: Yes it is. Strange I must not have noticed it before. Thanks!